# Showing pictures that uploaded on express server on react in a correct way

Tags: reactjs, api, express, multer

I built an express API and uploading images with multer .
in DB I save a post with image's name and I combine it with API link and show it in this way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbEHF.jpg)

but my problem is , I think this is not a good way to show uploaded pictures and users can see API link ، isn't it bad? i mean in a security issues

can you help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this really isn't an issue. There isn't any problem with people knowing your API URL. If someone uses something like postman to intercept the request, they'll find it out either way. You should however secure your API if there is important data on it.

Comment: is this the way that most of the people do?

Comment: Personally, I would use an S3 bucket, but for images, you'll always have to show the source